# Why is the Facebook API returning a missing post?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I'm using Facebook4J to obtain the feed of public pages. I tested it out on a public page and noticed that I received a null value for the message field of one of their posts.

I checked the created time of the post and went to compare with the actual Facebook page. Turns out the post doesn't exist on the page, which leads me to wonder if it has been deleted. If so, why is it still being returned by the API?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the GraphAPI will return even deleted posts but with an empty data set.